# Usernames with inappropriate language

Tags: support, feature-request, offensive

Can we have a filter for usernames that contain [vulgar words](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3528030/shit-implementor)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Oded describes [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/213181/135615), all you need to do is flag one of the posts by said user and explain why you believe the username to be offensive or inappropriate. We give some latitude with usernames, but generally will reset ones with obscenities in them.

Filtering for words, particularly on an international site like this, is [prone to false positives](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Clbuttic-Mistake-.aspx).